# echo'ing out a jquery .remove() function?

Tags: php, jquery

Im creating a blogging system with on page post editing.

If a user is logged in, and they created the blog post then they can see an edit button.

Currently, the edit button is always displayed but is set a display: none for non allowed users.

This works... but ofcourse some one can just change the styling to block with inspector on their browser and viola it works!

I have thought about this and when processing an update in my /updatepost.php page i do another check to see if the user has appropriate access before updating the database.

I dont want however the user to even be able to get this far.

My next idea was instead of setting the button to display none, i would echo a script to remove the button.

I tried e.g.:

```
if (!isset($userid)) {
    echo '<script> $("#editbutton").remove(); </script>';
}
```

but that doesnt seem to work.

I could go down the route of creating spans with the user id and the post owner id, then check the value .html() and then check if they match etc. But i prefer my first method.

Any ideas as to where my idea is going wrong?

Comment: When that Javascript is executed, does the Edit Button exist in the DOM yet?

Comment: _“Any ideas as to where my idea is going wrong?”_ – in trying to implement security measures that belong on the server side on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

This should be solved in php, no JavaScript required. Only print the edit button if the user can edit the post.

Comment: For security, I certainly agree with you. I hope there is back end code in place to protect regardless. :)

My answer was contrary in case there are other factors at work here, like AJAX updates where this may need to be there.

Comment: I will definitely come back to this in the future, however currently the edit button is output in amongst alot of other items. I could split the echo output but for now this will work. Checks are made server side as well when processing in backend :P

Comment: @user2921557 really there isn't another way to do this. If I have JavaScript disabled I could delete every post on your site. It must be done server-side.

Comment: @useSticks Even if you're building your form using an HTML response via AJAX, you can still check user credentials (its in Session somewhere, and you're using PHP to handle AJAX).

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is to type down a problem, hear the feedback others and you soon realise the right answer. Ill set about doing this now, no excuses or do it laters when it comes to security. Thanks for all the ideas however.

Comment: Np, but this isn't really a security thing heh. I guarantee you'll run into the same issue again (hide some control/function from non-admin users). Sounds like your templating layer needs some work!

Answer (score 1):

You are not using it in a document ready. That is probably the root issue. This is getting executed before your page is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Just the opposite, only write out the edit button (and other associated elements) if the user has sufficient privileges.

```
if (isset($userid)) {
    echo '<button id="editbutton">Edit</button>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($userid)) {
    // show edit button with no need for Javascript
}
```